# Why is some of my code light gray in VS 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015, and I am coding in c++. Some of my code is light gray and I have no idea why. There is also some other weird coloring in my code and I want to know what it means. I have attached pictures to show what I mean.

`delete` keyword is gray

[image: delete keyword is gray]

the "new" and "i" are gray but not "nt"

[image: the "new" and "i" are gray but not "nt"]

Comment: for the "new int" one, it is microsoft subliminally messaging you to use windows nt

Comment: @M.M:: Couldn't understand :(

Comment: It looks like it's how language keywords are displayed according to the color scheme of the IDE. Speaking of that, please tag your questions Studio.

Comment: Intellisense gets crazy sometimes. Try restarting VS

Comment: The colouring is called "syntax highlighting", you will easily find more info with those keywords. Normally, it should help reading code, but in this case it just malfunctions. Concerning the sublime message, that was a joke.